# Declaring a method after main method produces error in c

Tags: c

**This Code Compiles Correctly**

```
#include <stdio.h>
    void printMessage()
    {
      printf("HELLO WORLD\n");
    }

    int main()
    {
     printMessage();

    return 0;
    }
```

**This Piece of Code Produces an error**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printMessage();

return 0;
}
void printMessage()
{
  printf("HELLO WORLD\n");
}
```

The only difference is that in the first piece of code, the void method is written before the main method and in the the second piece of code the void method is written after the main method. However when I compile the second piece of code I get the following: 
[image]

```
hello.c:13:7: warning: conflicting types for 'printMessage' (enabled by default)
hello.c:7:2: note: previous implicit declaration of 'printMessage' was here
```

It could be something ridiculous I apologize in advance as I am brand new to C. Please advise.

Comment: This problem has been discussed many times!

Comment: you can declare you function by putting this before the main function

`void PrintMessage();`

Comment: C has functions, not "methods". And functions with no parameters should be defined and/or declared with `(void)`, not `()`; the latter is an obsolescent syntax indicating an unspecified number of parameters. (It's different in C++.)

Comment: It's better to copy-and-paste error messages into your question rather than including a screenshot. I've added the messages (hopefully without typos).

Comment: @KeithThompson sorry about that, thanks for clarification.

Comment: @user2733436 To get the proper chars to display (instead of â) in Putty, change this setting in your current Putty profile: Configuration -> Window -> Translation -> UTF-8. The character encoding that you want to use with the host that you're logged into is UTF-8.

Comment: @OregonTrail thanks for that tip! , i will change it. even though i do have a linux os on my laptop, i am working remotely on my school server .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C compiler needs a function to be declared before it can be called.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printMessage(void);

int main()
{
    printMessage();

    return 0;
}

void printMessage()
{
    printf("HELLO WORLD\n");
}
```

This is true except in C89, in which undeclared functions are implicitly declared with an `int` return type, which is what you encountered here.

The way that your code is compiled by a C89 compiler (the default behavior of gcc):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printMessage(void);

int main()
{
    printMessage();

    return 0;
}

void printMessage()
{
    printf("HELLO WORLD\n");
}
```

When the compiler reaches the line `void printMessage()`, it throws an error, because the function was already implicitly declared with an `int` return type.

In your question, when you defined the function before defining main, you also declared the function and its return type.

My suggestion, use the c99 or c11 standard. `gcc -o main --std=c11 main.c`

Comment: C doesn't require a prototype, it merely requires a declaration. (A prototype is a function declaration that specifies the types of the parameters; if there are no parmaters, a prototype uses `(void)` rather than `()`.)  Common sense and good style do require prototypes rather than old-style non-prototype declarations.

Comment: To be prototypes, not "signatures".

Comment: Yes, "to be prototypes declared with complete signatures"

Comment: Dont forget to compile with `gcc -Wall -g --std=c11 main.c -o main`

Comment: @OregonTrail: It's not clear what "signatures" means. The C standard doesn't use that term. It refers to function declarations, which may or may not be prototypes.

Comment: @KeithThompson Good to know, I haven't read the standard, yet.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in second case, the compiler has no way to know 'what is the behavior' of printMessage (it's signature: function name, return and parameters). That's why the code doesn't compile.

Try giving the signature first (which is called a function's prototype):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printMessage(void); //<-- here is the prototype
int main(void)
{
    printMessage();

return 0;
}
void printMessage(void)
{
  printf("HELLO WORLD\n");
}
```

Comment: `void printMessage();` is a function declaration, but it's not a prototype. To make it a prototype (which you definitely should do), change `()` to `(void)`.

Comment: And for the same reasons, `int main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: The `(void)` think is one of those corners of C that nobody ever bothers to get right, and is completely incompatible with C++, and therefore confusing. In practice getting it wrong leads to actual bugs so rarely that it might as well not be wrong.